# Redirect image links from old blog (Wordpress multisite)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have the following scenario:

- Everything runs on a wordpress multisite
- I used to have a blog on domain A
- The blog posts from domain A got transferred to a new blog on domain B. The images on this new blog were still pointing to domain A and were working fine, until...
- I created a new website on domain A with a different ID

Now the images on domain B point to domain A, to the upload folder of the old ID and they don't work anymore. I just copied the files from the old blog over to my new blog's ID's upload folder.

Now I guess I need to edit my htaccess file, which is the reason for this question. What's the code I need to use and where do I put it (I guess it goes in the main WP htaccess file)?

I need to redirect all image links from

```
http://domaina/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/XXXX/XX/XXX.xxx
```

to

```
http://domainb/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/XXXX/XX/XXX.xxx
```

I guess an alternative would be to do it in SQL and rewrite the permalinks, but that's quite high risk and I would prefer the htaccess solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use .htaccess than just put the redirects following the example

Redirect 301 /old-page.html http://new-domain.ru/new-page.html

and yes, use the main .htaccess in the root WP directory

Comment: Basically... Redirect 301 /wp-content/uploads/sites/5/ /wp-content/uploads/sites/9/